# What happens to the voice recognition scenario if the user hangs up?

Tags: voximplant

My scenario has speech recognition and several operations after the speech is converted to text. What if the client hangs up before all the operations are executed? Will the script stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to terminate the VoxEngine session in the call’s Disconnected event. You can process all the necessary logic and then terminate the session.